# What modern C compiler can I use to build this 1992 MS-DOS program?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I was given the source code to modify an MS-DOS program built back in 1992.  I have the EXE file and it runs fine, but I need to modify the source code.  The source code needs the below headers to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <alloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mem.h>
#include <values.h>
```

Does anyone know what was used and are there any modern compilers that can handle this?  I tried with Visual Studio 2010 and GCC "out of the box", but it fails because some headers are missing (dir.h, alloc.h, mem.h, values.h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Turbo C++ 1.01](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/21751), not so modern, though, that appears to have all these header files as well. I still occasionally use it.

Comment: I was able to get an old version of Turbo C++ 3 and it compiled with no problems. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

It might be more interesting to ask what what *function declarations, type declarations, global variable declarations and macros* it needs to have. The particular arrangement of those things into headers isn't very interesting as long as they are all there.

So comment out the offending `#includes` and let the compiler complain about the bits it is missing. *Then* you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the [Open Watcom](http://openwatcom.org/) compiler, which is one of the few relatively up-to-date compilers that builds 16-bit DOS executables.  Other than finding an old MS or Borland compiler (or whatever was originally used), that's probably the easiest route.

If you want to rebuild for a different platform instead of rebuilding for DOS again, you'll likely have to make a lot of changes to the program itself.  That may be worthwhile, but may be a lot of work and have a lot of surprise headaches.

Answer (score 4):

You might try using [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp). According to the [documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/incs/), it may have the headers you need.

Answer (score 1):

a) Remove all the header files
b) Try a compile
c) Look up which header file the undefined function/type is int
d) Add the header file
e) repeat

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a compiler to compile C for MS-DOS directly from Windows 10 as a host, but only from an MS-DOS emulator as a host (which is DOSBox) and the compiler that worked for me was Borland Turbo C++ 3.0. Here are the steps:

- download [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1)
- [install](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Basic_Setup_and_Installation_of_DosBox) it
- run it you will get a command prompt like `Z:\>`
- now back to Windows 10 for preparing a directory dedicated to DOSBox where we will work, for ex create one in your `C:\` drive and name it `DOS`, you can choose another path and name if you want
- back to DOSBox, in the prompt type:

  ```
  Z:\>MOUNT C C:\DOS
  Z:\>C:
  ```

the first command `MOUNT` will [mount](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/MOUNT) the `C:\DOS` directory (of your system) for DOSBox, so referencing `C:\SOMETHING` from inside DOSBox is like referencing a file `C:\DOS\SOMETHING` from your system. The second command `C:` will change your prompt to become `C:\>` like you are pointing into your new C drive (which in turn points to `C:\DOS` of your system) so typing `DIR` directly will list files and directories composing it

- now back to Windows and download [Borland Turbo C++ 3.0 zip](https://archive.org/details/tcc_20210425)
- unzip it inside `C:\DOS` so you will have `C:\DOS\TCC\TURBOC.EXE`
- go back to DOSBox and while in `C:\>` type:

  ```
  C:\>CD TCC
  C:\TCC>TURBOC.EXE
  ```

this will start the installer, you will get prompted with "some files already exist. Overwrite (y/n)?" so type "y" everytime

- the installer will create a bunch of files inside `TCC` that's the compiler files and most importantly we will use `TCC.EXE` to compile C files
- back to windows and put a C source file to compile (for ex `TEST.C`) inside the `DOS` folder
- back to DOSBox and still inside `TCC` folder, type:

  ```
  C:\TCC>TCC.exe -I. -L. C:\TEST.C
  ```

command explanation: `TCC.exe` is the compiler executable, `-I.` is a compiler option to say to use the current directory `.` as the Include directory, `-L.` is a compiler option to say to use the current directory `.` as the Libraries directory and `C:\TEST.C` is the full path to the C source file to compile

- the command will generate 2 new files inside `TCC` folder, `TEST.EXE` and `TEST.OBJ` (this is the object file you can delete it if you want), `TEST.EXE` is the compiled program you can test it by typing `TEST.EXE`
- inside Windows you can find it through the files in `DOS\TCC` that's your executable

Comment: Even though this somewhat duplicates -- but extends -- the selected answer, the updated links and well formatted answer will be appreciated. (but be wary of extending answers, the same won't apply in all cases) Borland Turbo C was the IDE that contained Turbo C (and Tasm - the Turbo assembler) It began as a DOS IDE in the DOS 3.3 days and through DOS 4.1 until Windows 286, 386 and 3.0 were released, it was then rewritten as a windows IDE. It was a good IDE for the time on the PC. Though today the compiler is quite outdated (but just fine for 1992 DOS programs)